# ThreeJS Load GLTF Model Directly From File Input

Tags: javascript, html, file, input, three.js

I need to load any GLTF Model in ThreeJS the user wants to display. That means I have a file input tage where the user can click and then choose a gltf-file he wants to upload from his file browser:

```
<input id="selectedModel" type="file">
```

As soon as the user has selected a model I want to use the file directly and display it in ThreeJS, the problem is I do not know how I can use the selected file right of the bat, without first saving it on the server.

I've tried doing it like this:

```
const uploadedFile = document.getElementById("selectedModel").files[0]

loadGLTF( uploadedFile , function ( gltf ) {        
    model = gltf.scene      
})
```

However this gives me an error:

```
url.lastIndexOf is not a function
```

I've also tried `document.getElementById("selectedModel").value` but this gives me a `fakepath` and ThreeJS cannot access this for some security reasons. What's the solution to this? Nothing I tried worked so far.

How can I display the model directly from the selected file in the input tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLTFLoader does not accept files, you need to pass in a URL.

You can create local temporary URLs from `File` or `Blob` objects and pass them in like this

```
const uploadedFile = document.getElementById("selectedModel").files[0]
const url = URL.createObjectURL(uploadedFile);
loadGLTF( url, function ( gltf ) {        
    model = gltf.scene;
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}, function (){  }, function (){ 
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

Assuming `loadGLTF` is same as `GLTFLoader.load()`. Second callback is for progress, third for error.
Make sure to revoke the URL even after failure.